# Difference between Duplication & Replication in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, duplicates, hdfs, replication

In the Hadoop Definitive Guide:

> A common way of avoiding data loss is through replication: redundant
> copies of the data are kept by the system so that in the event of
> failure, there is another copy available.

Why Tom White preferred to use the word *replication* and how is it different from *duplication*?

Comment: Duplication is possible... But how about triplication... Or even quadruplication... They are all possible in Hadoop. And the term replication describes all these cases quite well

Comment: [suggested reading](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html) There is some thing called `ReplicationFactor` which is by default 3.(triplication as told by @facha)